How can I monitor and verify the delivery of Firebase push notifications to all users in my React Native app with 5000+ users?
How can I monitor and verify the delivery of Firebase push notifications to all users in my React Native app with 5000+ users?
I implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) push notifications in my React Native app. On the test server, notifications are successfully sent and users are redirected to the related post when they click the notification, which also opens the app automatically.
Everything works as expected on the test server, so I am now planning to move this functionality to the live environment, where notifications will be sent to 5000+ users.

I think this might help
